# use rviz and urdf to simulate the differential_drive robot

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want use the rviz and urdf to simulate the differential_drive robot , and now I have got the robot model and can show in the rviz. I can publish the cmd_vel to let the robot move ,but here is the problem : **that I move the robot just change the entire robot's velocity and orientation , but I want to give the individual wheel speed to receive the same goal** ,so what can I do ?
please give me a hand. Thank u very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255061/use-rviz-and-urdf-to-simulate-the-differential_drive-robot/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-19**:
RViz is *not* a simulator. It is a visualisation tool. If you want to simulate dynamics, use Gazebo or V-REP or a similar tool.

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-02-19**:
so if I use the Gazebo,how can I move the robot by changing the individual wheel's velocity ?

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-02-19**:
thank u very much !  :)

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-02-20**:
hello, sorry to disturb you again , I read the diff_drive_controller  code in the github ,but have some problem with speed_limiter.cpp. I have been quiet confused with the "SpeedLimiter::limit(double& v, double v0, double v1, double dt)", how dose it work ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-20**:
I did not write that code, so I can't answer you right now. I'd advise you to open a new question.

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-02-20**:
ok,thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's up to you, but I'd look at `gazebo_ros_control` in combination with the [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller).

re: individual wheel velocity: that's not how we typically control mobile bases, but if you want, even that would be possible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0